# taking Sreen-shot in android

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take a screen shot of my Activity and components of Activity (View).

This Activity contains a SurfaceView and a layout on the top of each other.

When I take screen shot of Surface view it works well, but when I take screen shot of whole Activity I do not get the surface view in it. I am using the following code:

```
public class Screenshot {
  private final View view;
  /** Create snapshots based on the view and its children. */
  public Screenshot(View root) {
    this.view = root;
  }
  /** Create snapshot handler that captures the root of the whole activity. */
  public Screenshot(Activity activity) {
    final View contentView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    this.view = contentView.getRootView();
  }
  /** Take a snapshot of the view. */
  public Bitmap snap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.view.getWidth(), this.view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do as a workaround is capture both the layout **and** the `SurfaceView` images and draw the `SurfaceView` image over the layout image (using `Canvas.drawBitmap`) at the right coordinates using the properties of the `SurfaceView`.

Comment: that could be a great idea, but i have to save the screen hot as a bitmap, so that i can show the user the state of his Activity. This does not seem a feasible solution.

Comment: You *are* dealing with Bitmaps here. You just need to take two shots, one of the layout, one of the `SurfaceView`.

Comment: `Canvas.drawBitmap` ... it's in the answer! Use `getLeft` and `getTop` to get the coordinates of the `SurfaceView`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.view = contentView.getRootView();` to `this.view = contentView;`
Hope it will help.

Comment: Nopes..It does not include SurfaceView in screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to help or not but can't you just take the screen shot using DDMS directly?

**EDIT**

Have you tried getting the `Window` for the `Activity` and seeing what views/image cache you can pull out of that?

Comment: Sure i can. But I need it to take by code, so that i can use this image further. :)